# Cardinality of power sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

How would I find the cardinality of these two sets?

$\mathcal{P} (\{a,b,\{a,b\}\})$

$\mathcal{P} (\mathcal{P} (\emptyset))$

I believe the first set has a cardinality of 5 but I am not sure how the inner set works with power sets.

Comment: The size of a power set of a finite set is always a power of two.

Comment: The cardinality of a power set is 2 to the power of the cardinality of the original set (since each subset of the original set can be formed by choosing whether each element of the set is contained in it or not, 2 options for each element). The contents of the inner set don't affect the power set.

Comment: {a,b,{a,b}} has three elements.  P({a,b,{a,b}}) has $2^3$ elements.  $\emptyset$ has zero elements.  So P($\emptyset$) has $2^0$ elements.  So P(P($\emptyset$)) has $2^{2^0}$ elements.

Answer (score 2):

For a finite set $S$, the following formula holds:

$$|P(S)|=2^{|S|}$$

So $|P(\{a,b,\{a,b\}\})|=2^3=8$. Your second problem can be solved similarly:

$$|P(P(\emptyset))|=2^{|P(\emptyset)|}=2^{2^0}=2$$